# How to redirect after user log in with Iron Router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I want to redirect to '/' main page when user log in, I managed to redirect to '/'main page with this.render, but then it only shows main page and can't access other urls.

```js
Router.route('/', {name: 'yaksList'})

Router.route('/submit', {name: 'yaksSubmit'});

Router.route('/login', {name: 'accounts'});

Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  if (Meteor.userId()) {
    this.render('yaksList');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
});
```

I tried to use Router.go('yaksList') instead of this.render, but it's not working. What is the right solution, please ?

Comment: To clarify, you mean that you want the user to be redirected to '/' after the user successfully logs in? Not that the user be redirected from the login page to '/' anytime he or she visits the login page, right?

Answer (score 0):

There's a fine description of how to handle restricted routes [here](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/login-required-for-an-url-done-right).

Mr. Schoebel's approach let's you require a login to access certain routes. It puts up your login page in between if you try to access a restricted route directly and then takes you there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something easy like this on the `yaksList template`, using the `currentUser` helper.

```
{{#if currentUser}}
   {{> yaksList}}
{{else}}
   {{> login}}
{{/if}}
```

or use `router.go`.

`Router.go('yaksList');` //on the submit button.

**UPDATE**

> but they need to login when they want to upvote/downvote posts

use the validation on the event handler.

```
Template.yaksLists.events({
  'click #upVote':function(event,template){
    //some other code here
    //validation
    if(!Meteor.userId()){
      //here you redirect the user to the /login
      Router.go('/login');
     }else{
      //do the up vote stuff
     }
   }
})
```

Comment: The solution with handlebars {{#if currentUser}}... in template works, but then you can't access '/login' page to logout, you only see main page. How to make 'submit form' event on template.login.events ? I am using meteor accounts-twitter package and have no idea how to access submit

Comment: It supposed to work somehow similar as I pointed in code in my question. I mind explained it wrong. Users don't need to be logged viewing '/', but they need to login when they want to upvote/downvote posts. So when user click on upvote, it redirects them to '/login'. And now comes what I need. Basically now it works as you advices with {{#if currentUser}}, but I just wanted to accomplish the same with Router, to use it further. 
You can see simple demo here - http://week1.meteor.com/